# Adding a space to strings with underscrore in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I an trying to add an underscore to a space in a string using str_replace() in php but its not doing what i expect 
    This is what i am doing:

```
     echo $view="one bank".'<br>';
     echo $view_name=  str_replace("","_",$view);

The output:

    one bank
    one bank

What i wanted:

    one bank
    one_bank
```

Comment: You need a space `$view_name=  str_replace(" ","_",$view);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `""` into `" "` and it will work

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $view="one bank".'<br>';
echo $view_name=  str_replace(" ","_",$view);
```

You have to have a space to replace... You didn't have a space between your `""`.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $view_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $view_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
echo $view="one bank".'<br>';
 echo $view_name=  str_replace(" ","_",$view);
 ?>
```